# Multiple images on page - how to select any one easily

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm using Photoshop CC (new user).

I am creating a collage with 40 pictures.

All of the pictures import into a different layer.

If I want to move one image - I have to click on the layer first - then I can move the image - but this is very cumbersome.

Is there anyway for me to simply click on the image I want to move, and it becomes the image that I can move - without having to first find it in the layers panel?

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Comment: Hello Mark. Welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. If you have any questions about how Stack Exchange works (we're not just any forum!), please have a look at the [help]. Once your reputation on this site reaches 20, you can also pop into [chat] and join us there. Keep contributing and enjoy your time here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Select the Move tool, also known as the black arrow. It's the first tool in the box, with shortcut <kbd>v</kbd>.

With this tool active, while holding your <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Right click</kbd> the desired object with your mouse. That should select the layer that object is on.

Be aware that clicking a (mostly) transparent pixel will select the layer that that pixel is on, and not the things you see below it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just make sure "Auto-Select" and "Show Transform Controls" are are ticked when using the Move Tool.

[image]